# Python TCP socket for a lot of data

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

We (as project group) are currently stuck on the issue of how to handle live data to our server.

We are getting updates on data every second, and we would like to insert this into our database (security is currently not an issue, because it is a school project). The problem is here we tried python SockerServer and AsyncIO to create a TCP server to which the data can be sent.

We got this working with different libraries etc. But we are stuck on the fact that if we keep an open connection with the client (in this case hardware which sends data every second) we can't split the different JSON or XML messages. They are all added up together.

We know why because TCP only provides order.

Any thoughts on how to handle this? So that every message sent will get split from the others.

Recreating the socket won't be the right option if I recall correctly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: why dont you just make a rest api that gets called instead of a socket stream ... or just define some token to delimit messages

Comment: Because we think maybe the rest api approach will be less scale able if we get faster data. Like 0.5 seconds from different clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the client side (the thing sending the data), then you are going to have to parse the input. You can't just add a delimiter to something that you don't control.

An alternative is to use a header that encodes the size of the message that will be sent. Lets say you use a header of 4 bytes, The client first send the server a header with the size of the message to come. The client then sends the message (up to 4 gigs or there about). The server knows that it must first read 4 bytes (a header). It calculates the size `n` that the header contained then reads `n` bytes from the socket buffer. You are guaranteed to have read only your message. Using special delimiters is dangerous as you MUST know all possible values that a client can send.

It really depends on the type of data you are receiving. What type of connection, latency... If you have a pause of 1 second between packets and your connection is consistent, you could probably get away with first reading the entire buffer once to clear it, then as soon as there is data available - read it and clear the buffer it. not a great approach, but it might work for what you need - and no parsing involved.

Comment: We will try to implement the header part, this was very helpfull information.

Answer (score 1):

What you will have to do is ensure that there is a clear delimiter for each message. For example, the first 6 characters of every message could be the length of the message - whatever reads from the socket decodes the length then reads that number of bytes, and sends the data to whatever needs it. Another way would be if there is a character/byte which *never* appears in the content, send it immediately before a message - for example control-A (binary value 1) could be the leadin character, and send control-B (binary value 2) as the leadout. Again the server looks for these framing a message.

Comment: you can use a sequence as a delimiter Im guessing `"\xde\xad\xbe\xef"` makes a pretty good delimiter (but great answer +1)

Comment: Yes of course - anything unique - and the server should be designed to cope with occasional lost data and resynchronize to the delimiter when next looking for a message.

Comment: Yes that was my initial tought aswell, and that will probably work. The only problem was that we can't program the hardware sending the data to have some sort of framing message because the hardware is external(not our own sensors)

Comment: In that case you'll have to parse the json/xml data you are receiving, a byte at a time, and figure out when the stream is a complete because the text is a well-formed json/xml expression.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, this is very helpfull we will probably look a way to add frame, because parsing will be more extensive